# How to sort a list of dictionaries in Julia

Tags: dictionary, sorting, julia

```
portfolio = [
   ("name"=> "IBM", "shares"=> 100, "price"=> 91.2),
   ("name"=> "AAPL", "shares"=> 50, "price"=> 643.22),
   ("name"=> "FB", "shares"=> 150, "price"=> 21.09),
   ("name"=> "HPQ", "shares"=> 35, "price"=> 31.75),
   ("name"=> "YHOO", "shares"=> 45, "price"=> 16.35),
   ("name"=> "ACME", "shares"=> 75, "price"=> 115.65)
]
```

changed to

```
portfolio = [
       Dict("name"=> "IBM", "shares"=> 100, "price"=> 91.2),
       Dict("name"=> "AAPL", "shares"=> 50, "price"=> 643.22),
       Dict("name"=> "FB", "shares"=> 150, "price"=> 21.09),
       Dict("name"=> "HPQ", "shares"=> 35, "price"=> 31.75),
       Dict("name"=> "YHOO", "shares"=> 45, "price"=> 16.35),
       Dict("name"=> "ACME", "shares"=> 75, "price"=> 115.65)
    ]
```

How to sort this list of named tuples by "price"?

Added : How to use `findmin` and `findmax` with the list of Dict.

I have tried

```
 cheap = findmin(portfolio,by=x->x["price"])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching findmin(::Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}}; by=var"#23#24"())
Closest candidates are:
  findmin(::AbstractArray; dims) at reducedim.jl:1112 got unsupported keyword argument "by"
  findmin(::Any) at reduce.jl:977 got unsupported keyword argument "by"
  findmin(::Any, ::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseVector{T}) where T at C:\Users\Vinod\Downloads\Programs\julia-1.8.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\SparseArrays\src\sparsevector.jl:1430 got unsupported keyword argument "by"
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] kwerr(::NamedTuple{(:by,), Tuple{var"#23#24"}}, ::Function, ::Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}})
   @ Base .\error.jl:165
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[67]:1
```

and

```
 sort(collect(portfolio),by=x->x["price"])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  getindex(::Tuple, ::Int64) at tuple.jl:29
  getindex(::Tuple, ::Integer) at tuple.jl:30
  getindex(::Tuple, ::Colon) at tuple.jl:33
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#29#30")(x::Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}})
   @ Main .\REPL[70]:1
 [2] lt(o::Base.Order.By{var"#29#30", Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}, a::Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}, b::Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}})
   @ Base.Order .\ordering.jl:119
 [3] sort!
   @ .\sort.jl:505 [inlined]
 [4] sort!(v::Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}}, lo::Int64, hi::Int64, a::Base.Sort.MergeSortAlg, o::Base.Order.By{var"#29#30", Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}, t::Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}})
   @ Base.Sort .\sort.jl:589
 [5] sort!
   @ .\sort.jl:588 [inlined]
 [6] sort!
   @ .\sort.jl:661 [inlined]
 [7] #sort!#8
   @ .\sort.jl:722 [inlined]
 [8] sort(v::Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}}; kws::Base.Pairs{Symbol, var"#29#30", Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:by,), Tuple{var"#29#30"}}})
   @ Base.Sort .\sort.jl:769
 [9] top-level scope
   @ REPL[70]:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Pair so maybe use:

```
sort(portfolio, by = x -> x[3].second)
#sort(portfolio, by = x -> x[3][2])           # Alternative
#sort(portfolio, by = x -> Dict(x)["price"])  # Alternative
#6-element Vector{Tuple{Pair{String, String}, Pair{String, Int64}, Pair{String, Float64}}}:
# ("name" => "YHOO", "shares" => 45, "price" => 16.35)
# ("name" => "FB", "shares" => 150, "price" => 21.09)
# ("name" => "HPQ", "shares" => 35, "price" => 31.75)
# ("name" => "IBM", "shares" => 100, "price" => 91.2)
# ("name" => "ACME", "shares" => 75, "price" => 115.65)
# ("name" => "AAPL", "shares" => 50, "price" => 643.22)
```

In case you have a Dict your try would work.

```
portfolio = [
   Dict("name"=> "IBM", "shares"=> 100, "price"=> 91.2),
   Dict("name"=> "AAPL", "shares"=> 50, "price"=> 643.22),
   Dict("name"=> "FB", "shares"=> 150, "price"=> 21.09),
   Dict("name"=> "HPQ", "shares"=> 35, "price"=> 31.75),
   Dict("name"=> "YHOO", "shares"=> 45, "price"=> 16.35),
   Dict("name"=> "ACME", "shares"=> 75, "price"=> 115.65)
]

sort(portfolio, by = x -> x["price"])
#6-element Vector{Dict{String, Any}}:
# Dict("shares" => 45, "name" => "YHOO", "price" => 16.35)
# Dict("shares" => 150, "name" => "FB", "price" => 21.09)
# Dict("shares" => 35, "name" => "HPQ", "price" => 31.75)
# Dict("shares" => 100, "name" => "IBM", "price" => 91.2)
# Dict("shares" => 75, "name" => "ACME", "price" => 115.65)
# Dict("shares" => 50, "name" => "AAPL", "price" => 643.22)
```

In case you have a named Tuple:

```
portfolio = [
   (name = "IBM",  shares = 100, price = 91.2),
   (name = "AAPL", shares = 50,  price = 643.22),
   (name = "FB",   shares = 150, price = 21.09),
   (name = "HPQ",  shares = 35,  price = 31.75),
   (name = "YHOO", shares = 45,  price = 16.35),
   (name = "ACME", shares = 75,  price = 115.65)
]

sort(portfolio, by = x -> x.price)
#6-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:name, :shares, :price), Tuple{String, #Int64, Float64}}}:
# (name = "YHOO", shares = 45, price = 16.35)
# (name = "FB", shares = 150, price = 21.09)
# (name = "HPQ", shares = 35, price = 31.75)
# (name = "IBM", shares = 100, price = 91.2)
# (name = "ACME", shares = 75, price = 115.65)
# (name = "AAPL", shares = 50, price = 643.22)
```

Comment: How to use findmin and findmax ? Updated the qn

Comment: With the updated data: `findmin(x->x["price"], portfolio)`

Answer (score 2):

You have not list of named tuples but a list of tuples containing pairs.
A list of named tuples would be:

```
 portfolio = [
          (name= "IBM", shares= 100, price= 91.2),
          (name= "AAPL", shares= 50, price= 643.22),
          (name= "FB", shares= 150, price= 21.09),
          (name= "HPQ", shares= 35, price= 31.75),
          (name= "YHOO", shares= 45, price= 16.35),
          (name= "ACME", shares= 75, price= 115.65)
       ]
```

Having a list of named tuples you could do:

```
sort!(portfolio, by = row->row.price)
```

Note

Comment: How to use findmin and findmax ? Updated the qn

Comment: assuming that you have a list of named tuples (as in my example):  `findmin(getindex.(portfolio,:price))`
BTW try `using DataFrames; DataFrame(portfolio)` - working with data frames is far more convenient